# uitextfield where arithmetic or pointer type is required.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, pointer-arithmetic

I have following code and got the error as shown in screen shots. What does this error means

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.tag<10) {

        if ((textField.text.length >= 1) && (string.length > 0))
        {

            NSInteger nextText = textField.tag + 1;
            // Try to find next responder
            UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextText];
            if (! nextResponder)
                [textField resignFirstResponder];
               // nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:1];

            if (nextResponder){
                // Found next responder, so set it.
                [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

                UITextField* nextTextfield= (UITextField) [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextText];
                [nextTextfield setText:string];
                return NO;

            }

        }
    }

    return YES;

}
```

I got following error in following conditions. i was unable to find the soluitions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextField` should be set as a pointer (`*` sign) like this:

```
UITextField* nextTextfield = (UITextField *) [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextText];
```

Comment: Thanks i found the solutions